# Understanding UITabBarController subclass initializer code in Obj- C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate

I found a project on GitHub and am trying to implement it in my Swift project. I am stuck on the syntax of the following line:

```
YALFoldingTabBarController *tabBarController = (YALFoldingTabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
```

I cannot figure out how to initialize this line in the AppDelegate. Any help and explanation into what this line means would be appreciated. The project can be found [here](https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should translate to something like

```
let tabBarController: YALFoldingTabBarController = self.window.rootViewController as! YALFoldingTabBarController
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if let tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController as? YALFoldingTabBarController {

}
```

This line doesn't do much though. All it's doing is casting from `UIViewController` to `YALFoldingTabBarController`.